# Scala 2.10.2 How to convert a HashMap to XML

Tags: xml, scala, hashmap

I have the following code

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

class Year(val y : String, val m : HashMap[String, Int]) {

  def toXML =
 <year>
   <number>{y}</number>
  {m.foreach(month2XML(_))}
</year>

def month2XML(m : (String, Int)) : xml.Elem = <month><s>{m._1}</s><d>{m._2}</d></month>

}

object Year {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  val a : Year = new Year("2014", HashMap[String, Int]("January" -> 31, "February" -> 28))

    println(a.toXML)
  }
}
```

which should return something like

```
<year>
   <number>2014</number>
   <month><s>January</s><d>31</d><s>February</s><d>28</d></month>
</year>
```

but the 'month' node is skipped instead the output is merely

```
<year>
   <number>2014</number>

</year>
```

What is the correct code to convert a HashMap to XML?

Comment: Well, first off, `foreach` is for side effects `map` is for transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. `foreach` is for side-effects, `map` is for transformations. (`m.foreach(month2XML)` should be `m.map(month2XML)`.)
2. You are returning `<month>` nodes for each entry in the `HashMap` when you only want to return nodes for `s` and `d`.

   ```
   def toXML =
     <year>
       <number>{y}</number>
       <month>{m.map(month2XML)}</month>
     </year>
   ```

   and update `month2XML` to return just the inner nodes:

   ```
   def month2XML(m : (String, Int)) : xml.Elem = <s>{m._1}</s><d>{m._2}</d>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sean!
That's the fix already (only class Year) object Year is not modified.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

class Year(val y : String, val m : HashMap[String, Int]) {

  def toXML =
<year>
   <number>{y}</number>
   {m.map(map2XML(_))}
</year>

def map2XML(m : (String, Int)) : xml.Elem = <month><s>{m._1}</s><d>{m._2}</d></month>

}
```

which gives the output

```
<year>
   <number>2014</number>
   <month><s>January</s><d>31</d></month><month><s>February</s><d>28</d></month>    <month><s>March</s><d>31</d></month>
</year>
```